# I need help with UpdateForm(); (Windows Forms Aplication)

Tags: c#, forms

Hey, I cant quite figure out how to create the object for Updating the Form. (Windows Forms Aplication). I'm doing a project from a book that requires me to make a Dog Racing program.
I need to update the Picture box of the Dogs so that they will move. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are dogs racing in a horse racing program?

Comment: Are you presenting *all* the dogs in one PictureBox, or a different dog in each PictureBox?

Comment: All of the dogs are moving at a random rate. So I guess all of them need to update their positions at once so that it's Real Time.

Comment: Oh. And every dog is in a different PictureBox.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this is follow these steps:

1. Add an object to your form of System.Windows.Forms.Timer
2. Set it's interval.
3. Set it's enabled to true.
4. Create a event handler that responds to the Tick event.

In the event handler you can do the move of the picture boxes. You'll probably want to store a random number for each picture box for the rate of movement. You'll also need a way to limit how far across the form the boxes can move.

Here's proof of concept in code form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _rate = new Random().Next(1, 10);

        _timer = new Timer() { Interval = 100, Enabled = true };
        _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.pictureBox1.Location.X > (this.Size.Width - this.pictureBox1.Size.Width))
        {
            return;
        }

        Point newLocation = this.pictureBox1.Location;
        newLocation.X += _rate;
        this.pictureBox1.Location = newLocation;
    }

    private int _rate;
    private Timer _timer;
}
```